# Bayesian updating of prior with positive result from underpowered test

Tags: bayesian

How should one update the beliefs about a probability of a theory being true given a positive result (meaning confirming the theory in a statistically significant way) of an underpowered study?

Let:

- P(G) = prior probability of Genuine theory.
- P(F)=1-P(G) = prior prob. of false theory
- P(+/G) = power = probability of positive result given genuine theory
- P(+/F) = significance level ($\alpha$) = prob of positive result given false theory

Then by Bayes rule:

$P(G/+) = \frac{P(+/G)P(G)}{P(+/G)P(G) + P(+/F)P(F)} = \frac{P(+/G)P(G)}{P(+/G)P(G) + \alpha(1-P(G))} $

Let P(+/G) -> 0. As the study becomes more and more underpowered P(G/+) -> 0.

But shouldn’t an underpowered study simply have no effect on my prior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are confounding a notion from classical statistics ("statistically significant way") with Bayesian statistics, which is, generally speaking, a mistake.
2. In a classical framework, your $P(+|G)$ can't go to zero, instead, it goes to whatever the significance level you are testing at is, e.g., 0.05.   At that point, $P(+|G) = P(+|F)$ and cancels out of the numerator and denominator in:

$$P(G|+) = {P(+|G)P(G) \over P(+|G)P(G) + P(+|F)P(F)} = {P(G) \over P(G)+P(F)} =P(G)$$

as $P(G)+P(F) = 1$.

So... your intuition is correct; at the limit, where the study has no power, it will have no effect on your prior.

Comment: Tks, Your comment cleared my puzzle). Regarding point 1, would you be ok if I just removed the "statistically significant way" from my original comment? Or is this whole exercise an inconsistent mix of frequentist and bayesian thinking?

Comment: Yes, I think so, or perhaps you could leave it in but clarify that that is an example of how you might get a positive result.  In real life, sometimes the experiment and subsequent analysis that was done is out of your control, and what you see is "positive / not positive at the $\alpha$ level of confidence", and that's your information, so it's not a bad example, actually.

Comment: Tks again. I guess I am still having trouble imagining what does a "positive" result from an experiment would mean in a Bayesian sense, without frequentist hypothesis testing.

Comment: It would mean the probability of seeing that result under the alternative > than seeing it under the null.  In frequentist thinking, that would be the probability of seeing that result or a more extreme one is "small" under the null, but in Bayesian thinking, we don't care about "more extreme" and we do care about the probability under the alternative.